# Where to initialize sentry.init in a react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sentry

In my react native application, to track errors I'm going to use sentry. So, where exactly should I use `Sentry.init`?

I tried to use this in app.ts, inside useEffect. But, if there are any error before loads the app, those errors are not tracked with this.

Where should I use this code to work sentry properly?

```
 Sentry.init({
    dsn: SENTRY_DSN,
    environment: ENVIRONMENT,
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projects I use like this and I got all errors (before App component)

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react-native';
Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://71c4b3f6a9b646c992175aa6cc095c08@o312251.ingest.sentry.io/1781718'
});


export default class App extends Component {
...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this satisfy the question, what if I get a native error before the App loads? I will reply it below with what I believe is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/manual-setup/native-init/

This will capture native crashes that happens before sentry initialization on the JS side